# How to reduce return content size from Slack rtm.start api

Tags: slack-api, slack

The api doc can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start).

I connect to this `rtm.start` api as a **bot user**:

`https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token=BOT_TOKEN` , but as the doc described:

> This method returns lots of data about the current state of a team, along with a WebSocket Message Server URL

acutally the only content I care about is the `WebSocket Message Server URL`.

currently, I'll get about 19MB content from this api(as we are a big team with many channels and users).

It take too long for my code to make this request and sometimes cause a timout. I can increase timeout time, but as I only want the `wss` url and make the Websocket call, any idea how to decrease the content size from this api?

I know some parameters like `simple_latest` & `no_unreads` & `mpim_aware` can be used. I've tried them with `https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token=BOT_TOKEN&simple_latest=true&no_unreads=1&mpim_aware=true` or something like this but did not work.

I also want to know how to make these three optional parameters work.

Answer (score 0):

`no_unreads=1` is the correct way to use these three parameters.

And I got another way: as per contact with Slack team, I got an additional parameter which did not appear in document:

`cache_ts` ==> a timestamp like **1479103245436** which indicating the latest timestamp event the client has cached.

Per my test, I set the `cache_ts` to `now` and the response content decrease from 19MB to 1MB.